# which facebook sdk library do I use for the open graph

Tags: .net, facebook, documentation, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

Since I'm scrambling with this project here, simple question. I see three parts to the facebook-sdk for C#.

http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Facebook

http://nuget.org/List/Packages/FacebookWeb

http://nuget.org/List/Packages/FacebookWebMvc

NONE of them have any decent description as to what they are. The codeplex docs are also kinda poor. I also don't see the most important thing around, authentication and authorization? [Theres nothing there.](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Authentication%20Examples&referringTitle=Documentation)

Could someone

1. Tell me which Package would I need when writing an asp.net mvc3 app that would need to authenticate with facebook and then publish posts to a users wall.
2. Point me to some documentation on authentication, authorization and anything on the open graph with the C# SDK.

Thanks a ton.
Gideon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for mvc you need all three packages.

```
Install-Package FacebookWebMvc
```

FacebookWebMvc also installs Facebook and FacebookWeb as dependency.

there is a folder called "Samples" in the source code demonstrating its use.